# Iterating grep over and over. How can I make my script faster?

Tags: performance, shell, optimization, grep, sh

I have to find a string of numbers from one file in another file. 
My code is this:

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS="F"
while read f1 f2
do
  LC_ALL=C fgrep -m 1 "$f1" BC_Tel.inp
done < telephonelist.txt
```

The string of numbers are located in telephonelist.txt. The format of this text file is as follows:

```
8901040000001304669F    370040000130466 
8901040000001317380F    370040000131738 
8901040000001330045F    370040000133004 
8901040000001330052F    370040000133005 
8901040000001330060F    370040000133006
```

I'm looking for the lines with the above numbers delimited by 'F' in BC_Tel.inp, which has the following format:

```
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
```

telephonelist.txt and BC_Tel.inp are huge files with over a million lines. The script works fine but I want to make it faster. I'm basically running over the txt file once, but I'm greping over and over the .inp file. How do I go about making this process faster?

tl;dr 
I want to optimize my code so it runs faster.

Comment: Is the idea here simply to find every line in the `.inp` that matches any of the first fields (without the trailing `F`) in the `.txt` file? Which field in the `.inp` file is that being matched against (none of your sample lines appear in there anywhere that I can tell).

Comment: Yes that's the idea. The field in the `.inp` that it's being matched to is the next to last one.

Comment: `-m 1` only matches one line (so multiple lines won't get matched). Something more like `LANG=C fgrep -w -f <(awk '{$0=$1; gsub(/F$/, "")}7') BC_tel.inp` might do what you want. That being said if you have the memory to store the fields from the `.txt` file in memory an awk script might be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

A single `grep` will do it:

```
cut -d"F" -f1 telephonelist.txt | grep -F -m1 -f- BC_Tel.inp
```

the `-f` option to grep provides a filename containing the patterns. Here, we're using the filename `-` to indicate "stdin".

Comment: This works but my `.inp` file is actually as long as the telephonelist.txt. I just put the example to show how the format was. How can I make this work so it goes through all the numbers in telephonelist.txt and not just the first one?

Comment: I don't understand your concern: the `cut` command will output *all* the numbers from telephonelist, not just the first one.